# Electron - Why is there a big delay when loading the main window through localhost compared to an HTML file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, electron

When loading my main window by passing the HTML file directly through Electron, everything works as expected.

Electron app:

```
mainWindow.loadURL(
  url.format({
    pathname: path.join(__dirname, "mainWindow.html"),
    protocol: "file:",
    slashes: true
  })
);
```

---

But when using Express and accessing the main window through `localhost`, there is a big delay (white screen) at the first launch of the Electron app which lasts for about 30 seconds.

However, The page is accessible through `localhost` in the browser as soon as the I run `electron .`

Express app:

```
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "mainWindow.html"));
});
app.listen(3000);
```

Electron app:

```
mainWindow.loadURL("http://localhost:3000");
```

I've tried this with multiple ports and they all give the same result.

Comment: The first thing to identify is where the delay(s) is/are. Compare the time when you launch the electron app to the time your Express server gets the request.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder the express server receives the request instantly and I can access localhost through the browser right away as I've said. But In electron, I've to wait ~30 seconds for it to load.

Comment: No, I mean when you launch the Electron app, how long after that does the Express server receive the request from Electron? Immediately, but you don't see the result for 30 seconds? After 10 seconds, then you see the result 20 seconds after that? Not until nearly the end of the 30 seconds, and then the result appears almost immediately?

Comment: What version of electron are you running?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder
Start Electron app ---30 seconds---> Express receives request ---no delay ---> Express sends response ---no delay---> Electron displays the page.

Comment: @Keith electron:4.1.4 , express: 4.16.4

Comment: There was issues with proxy detection in earlier version, but I was under the assumption it was fixed in 4,.  But it might be worth still trying this -> `app.commandLine.appendSwitch('auto-detect', 'false')
app.commandLine.appendSwitch('no-proxy-server')`

Comment: @Keith It worked!! Do you have any idea why this happens?! And also if you can post it as an answer so that other people who encounter this problem can find the solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Browsers can sometimes try to be a bit more clever than they need too,  proxy server's used to be common in the early days of the web.  And in co-operate companies they are still popular.  But in most case's proxy servers can be handled transparently by the OS, so why browsers still try to handle this I'm not 100% sure.

But the easy fix is to tell the embedded Chromium not to try a resolve the proxy server.

```
app.commandLine.appendSwitch('auto-detect', 'false');
app.commandLine.appendSwitch('no-proxy-server')
```

You may not need both the above switches.

Of course if you app is running on a system that does use a proxy, it might have issues.  But I've a feeling even then it's unlikely to cause an isssue, as hopefully the OS would be handling this anyway.

Also this might be handy keeping an eye on -> https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/13829